# Conda version pip install -r requirements.txt --target ./lib

Tags: installation, pip, conda, virtualenv

What is the conda version of this?

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt --target ./lib
```

I've found these commands:

```bash
while read requirement; do
    conda install --yes $requirement
done < requirements.txt
```

But it doesn't tell how to specify `--target ./lib`

Comment: did you try `conda install --file requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 310):

You can run `conda install --file requirements.txt` instead of the loop, but there is no target directory in [conda install](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html). `conda install` installs a list of packages into a specified conda environment.

Comment: When I do this on my `requirements.txt` specifying versions of packages, I get `InvalidVersionSpec: Invalid version '3.0.': empty version component`

Comment: There us no target directory for in `conda install`. However specifying a location for a virtual environment is possible with the `--prefix` optional argument ([doc](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#specifying-a-location-for-an-environment)) and target environment specifications can be given with  the `--name` or `--prefix` optional arguments ([doc](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Target%20Environment%20Specification)).

Comment: what do you mean by `conda install installs a list of packages into a specified conda environment.`? For me it usually installs it for whatever conda env is active at the moment.

Comment: @CharlieParker The OP wanted to install to a different directory; `pip` can do this but `conda` probably cannot.

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś It looks like you need to change `3.0.` to `3.0`, but I'm not an expert by any means. I guess pip is permissive about this but conda not.

Answer (score 110):

To create an environment named `py37` with python 3.7, using the channel conda-forge and a list of packages:

```
conda create -y --name py37 python=3.7
conda install --force-reinstall -y -q --name py37 -c conda-forge --file requirements.txt
conda activate py37
...
conda deactivate
```

Flags explained:

- `-y`: Yes, do not ask for confirmation.
- `--file`: Take the next argument as a filename.
- `--force-reinstall`: Install the package even if it already exists.
- `-q`: Quiet, do not display progress bar.
- `-c`: Channels, additional channels to search for packages. These are URLs searched in the order

Alternatively you can create an [environment.yml](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually)  file instead of requirements.txt:

```yaml
name: py37
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - numpy=1.9.*
  - pandas
```

Use these commands to create and activate the conda environment based on the specifications in the Yaml file:

```
conda env create --file environment.yml
conda activate py37
```

Use this command to list the environments you have:

```
conda info --envs
```

Use this command to remove the environment:

```
conda env remove --name py37
```

**New!** The ansible-role [dockpack.base_conda](https://galaxy.ansible.com/dockpack/base_conda) can manage conda environments on Linux, Mac and Windows, and can be used to create a docker image with custom conda environments.

Comment: explaining the flags would be useful

Comment: Is there any reason why after the 2nd command above python3 is removed from the environment and python2 is the only one remaining?

Comment: conda manages python environments, conda deactivate resets your shell, conda activate py37 sets your PATH.

Comment: It could be usefull if you add where to put yaml file and how to install environment from it. I guess environment doesn't simply come to existence if you have yaml file.

Comment: @Ataxias was very right, the flag explanations are very helpful. +1!

Answer (score 23):

You can always try this:

```
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This simply uses the pip installed in the conda environment. If pip is not preinstalled in your environment you can always run the following command

```
conda install pip
```

Comment: Just pip install -r requirements.txt works great for me.

Comment: python -m pip install -r requirements.txt with activated conda env

Comment: Same as above, once I activated the `conda` environment, I just did `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 5):

A quick search on the [conda official docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands.html#conda-general-commands) will help you to find what each flag does.

So far:

- `-y`: Do not ask for confirmation.
- `-f`: I think it should be `--file`, so it read package versions from the given file.
- `-q`: Do not display progress bar.
- `-c`: Additional channel to search for packages. These are URLs searched in the order

Answer (score 2):

would this work?

```bash
cat requirements.txt | while read x; do
    conda install "$x" -p ./lib
done
```

or

```
conda install --file requirements.txt -p ./lib
```

Comment: best solution for me:  cat requirements.txt | while read x; do conda install -y "$x" ;done

Comment: i like that one, it could possibly run slower, but more reliable.

Comment: FWIW, this is a [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat). OP had it cleaner: `while read ... done < requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can easily run the following command to install all packages in requirment.txt with an additional channel to search for packages:

```
conda install -c conda-forge --file requirements.txt
```